# Is the regex wrong or is it my code?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

def street_regex(street):
    street_regex = ""

    regex = re.compile("^(\p{L}[\p{L} -]*\p{L}(?: \d{1,4}(?: ?[A-Za-z])?)?\b)")
    s = regex.search(street)

    if s:
        street_regex = s.group()
    else:
        street_regex = street

    return street_regex
```

So that is my code. From one of my [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070890/regex-python-wont-work-as-i-want-it) on here I got the regex that I'm using in my code. However if I call my function then the regex wont work and I don't get what i want. (See the previous post to understand what I mean). I'm using Python 3.4 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `re module` does not support Unicode properties. However, if you set the `re.UNICODE` flag, `\w` matches alphanumerics from all scripts. Hence, `[^\W\d_]` matches only letters, as the intended `\p{L}`.

- `\W` matches non-word characters (excluding the `Letter category`, the `Number category`, and "`_`")
- `\d` matches digits included in the `Number category`
- So `[^\W\d_]` will match anything EXCEPT non-word characters, digits or "`_`"... which means it will only match letters

**Code:**

```python
#python 3.4.3
import re

str = u"Stréêt -Name 123S"
r = re.compile(r'^([^\W\d_](?:[^\W\d_]|[- ])*[^\W\d_](?: [0-9]{1,4}(?: ?[A-Za-z])?)?\b)', re.UNICODE)
s = r.search(str)
print(s.group())
```

[Run this code online](http://rextester.com/AJD40324)

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`regex module`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), with added support for Unicode properties

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `regex` module. Your regex is correct but the python's default regex module `re` won't support these `\p{L}`, `\p{N}` kind of pcre regex patterns. You may use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\p{L}` with `re` but it must support english alphabets only not any kind of letter from any language (`\p{L}`).

```
>>> import regex
>>> re.search(r'\p{L}+', 'foo')
>>> regex.search(r'\p{L}+', 'foo')
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
>>>
```